# Example of an adiabatically perturbed integrable 2 d.o.f. Hamiltonian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

Consider the following (classical) Hamiltonian system: $H(u,v,p,q, \tau)$, where $(u,v)$ and $(p,q)$ are conjugated variables and $\tau = \epsilon t$ is a slowly varying parameter, $0 < \epsilon << 1$, and $t$ is time.

Assume that:

1. For each fixed $\tau$, Hamiltonian is integrable, and decouples into a product of a rotor + pendulum.
2. Mathematically, this means that in terms of $(u,v)$ the phase space consists of closed periodic orbits only and hence action angle variables $I, \varphi$ can be introduced for each fixed $\tau$;
3. In terms of $(p,q)$ variables, the phase space resembles that of a pendulum, with a hyperbolic fixed point and a homoclinic to it, i.e. $\frac{p^{2}}{2} + \cos q - 1 $, for each fixed $\tau$.

The slow perturbation couples the system and it becomes no longer integrable. The fixed point in $(p,q)$ persists and gives rise to a Normally Hyperbolic Invariant Manifold, with associated local stable / unstable manifolds.

I have two questions:

1. What would be an explicit example of such Hamiltonian?
2. I want to introduce A-A variables for the "totally elliptic" part of the Hamiltonian, so that I'd have $H(I, \varphi, p,q, \tau)$. When I transfer to action-angle variables would they depend on $(u,v, \tau)$ only, or also on $(p,q)$? In other words, do we seek the transformation as $I(u,v,p,q, \tau)$ or $I(u,v, \tau)$?